# Issue with multiple jquery progressbar labels

Tags: jquery-ui, progress-bar

I'm facing an issue with jquery-ui progressbar labels.

I'm trying to do a single code that will handle multiple progress bars, in the fiddle I'm providing you will notice that bars are working perfect but I cannot solve the labels, I always get the last `data-width` value, when I'm looking to display the value of **each one** of the bars.

Have a look please: http://jsfiddle.net/jotapee/TRuND/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is on this line :

```
$('.progress-label').text(width.toFixed(0) + "%");
```

When you set text, BOTH labels with .progress-bar class will be called.

Here is one possible solution : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/K9MfR/)

In HTML:

```
<p><strong class="plabel">Master Plan</strong><span class="progress-label index-0"></span>
<p><strong class="plabel">Design</strong><span class="progress-label index-1"></span>
```

In .js:

```
$('.index-'+index).text(width.toFixed(0) + "%");
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of my issue and that clever solution rusln.

Comment: Np, glad i could help. My solution was ment to show that you need a way to distinguish between each progress-label, there are lots of different ways to do that.